# Getting an error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I tried to run a parallel analysis in the psych package that has worked before with almost identical data, however, this time it will not work.

I am having the error :

```
Warning: NaNs producedError in if (any(lower > upper)) stop("lower>upper integration limits") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This is with the code : `fa.parallel(ef2part_fc, fm = "pa", cor = "poly", fa = "fa")` , it is strange because i have run the same code for similar data frames around 15 times and it is just this df that will not work. I have checked the data and nothing weird is going on and it is the same as the other df's that have worked.

The data frame consists of around 25 categorical variables with large amounts of missing data.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, by providing the output of `dput(ef2part_fc)`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Unfortunately the data is sensitive and confidential so i cant share the dput here. However, i have checked it and there is nothing going on that shouldn't be there. It is the numbers assigned to the categorical values and lots of NA's. This is the end part:   format.stata = "%20.0g", class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"), labels = c(`Not Important` = 1, 
    `Slightly Important` = 2, `Moderately Important` = 3, `Highly Important` = 4
    ))), row.names = c(NA, -13948L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")

Comment: It's very difficult to help without a reproducible example of some kind. However, it is likely that the error is due to the high amount of missingness.

Comment: @Phil agreed, especially given that the code works on the OP's other dfs. The key part of the error message is "stop("lower>upper integration limits")". Not familiar with the methods you're using but the lower values are exceeding the upper values, most likely due to missingness. Could you create a df of the sample you provided in your comment and dput() that? Or a dput() of an anonymised version of your dataset? I couldn't create a reproducible df from the code you supplied.

Comment: Hi All, Thank you for your responses. I have started using the only complete cases (which i assumed it would anyway) and it seems to be working now.